# c# Ошибка присваивания

Tags: c#

Добрый день, есть вот такой код:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       const string a = ""; 
       Console.WriteLine("Представьтесь");
       a = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Хочу считать текст в переменную а. И выдает ошибку - левая часть выражения присваивания должна быть переменной свойством или индексатором
В чем проблема?

Comment: `/*const*/ string a = "";`

Answer (score 8):

Ваша переменная "a" является константой, т.к. стоит ключевое слово const. Ее значение нельзя изменить. Уберите ключевое слово const и все будет работать. 
Можете переписать Ваш код на такой:

```
Console.WriteLine("Представьтесь");
string a = Console.ReadLine();
```

Дело в том, что константа после инициализации значения не может меняться до конца работы программы.

Answer (score 2):

Вы объявили переменную `a` как константу.

> Константа (constant) — это идентификатор, значение которого никогда не
>   меняется.

Поскольку значение константы внедряется прямо в код, в период выполнения память для констант не выделяется и следовательно Вы не можете изменить ее значение.

Для того, чтобы в переменную можно было записать и считать, объявите ее следующим образом:

```
string a = String.Empty;
```